# Update and remove not working in nested document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My two mongoose functions (update and remove) do not throw any errors but do not update / remove anything.

I've tried looking into the "$" operator but this didn't help anything (the same issue still happened). Most of the tutorials I have found, dealt with only updating / removing things that are not nested. My understanding of manipulating nested documents is weak.

User model

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    decks: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Deck'}]
});

const deckSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, require: true },
    cards: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Card'}]
});

const cardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    front: { type: String },
    back: { type: String },
    example: [{ type: String }]
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Card = mongoose.model('Card', cardSchema);
const Deck = mongoose.model('Deck', deckSchema);
module.exports = {User, Card, Deck}
```

mongoose remove / update

```
    const removeDeck = async (userId, deckId) => {
        return user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: userId },
            {
                $pull: { decks: { _id: deckId } }
            }
        )
    }

    const removeCard = async (userId, cardId) => {
        return rCard = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: userId },
            {
                $pull: { decks: { cards:  {   _id: cardId } } }
            }
        )
    }


    const updateDeckName = async (userId, deckId, updatedName) => {
        const newDeck = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                _id: userId,
                decks: { $elemMatch: {_id: deckId}}
            },
            {
                $set: { 'decks.name': updatedName }
            }
        )
        return newDeck
    }

    const updateCard = async (userId, cardId, updatedText) => {
        return await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: userId, 'decks.cards._id': cardId },
            {
                $set: { 'cards.front': updatedText.front, 'cards.back': updatedText.back }
            }
        )
    }
```

No errors are thrown but both of the update functions return null.

Comment: Inside your `cards` have no _id field

Comment: I thought _id was automatically added? When i look at the mongoDB gui the cards have an _id field

Comment: `_id` automatically added to a document, not its field

Comment: Okay great. I understand! :). Do i add that as just _id: { type: String }?

Comment: You can if you need, but it should have type `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` if it refer to another model

Comment: So. Should i break up the card into a different Schema?

Comment: It all up to you. i don't know how your app work.

Comment: Unfortunately It's still not working. I changed the Schema to references a new card schema. Still not able to get things removed / updated any advice?

Comment: Can you editted your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196417/discussion-between-joshua-jones-and-cuong-le-ngoc).